# How to run heroku commands in Ruby file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I want to run heroku commands (such as 'heroku scale worker=5') in a ruby on rails class. Example:

```
class Foo
  def self.perform
    Heroku.run('heroku scale worker=10')
  end
end
```

Is there a gem or plugin to handle this?

Comment: You can use their API or simply use backticks `\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there's the heroku-api gem:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb

HTH?